# Python3 xlutils.copy

Tags: python, excel

I use `xlutils.copy()` to copy an excel file I opened using `xlrd`. 
Then I proces the excel file, get the relevant data and add comments using `xlwr.write()` for the lines I used in the copied excel file. 
Last step is to save the copied excel file using `xlwr.save()`. 
So far, so good. The essentiel part of the code looks like this.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy

    rb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    # print (rb)
    wb = copy(rb)
    # print (wb)
    sheet = rb.sheet_by_name(MNS Brandmelders')
    wsheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

    os.remove(file)
    os.chdir(path_opslag)
    # wb.save(file)
    os.chdir(path)
    continue
```

In the example above the wb.save command has been disabled. 
I wrote the script on my laptop running Windows7 and Python3.5.1.
If however I copy the file to the production environment it reports an error on the last save command. Production also on Windows 7 with python 3.5.1.

`AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Comment: Are you aware missing `'` on `sheet_by_name` argument?

Comment: I am also facing same issue.